# Trouble Creating Function To Check For A Specific Format Of A String

Tags: vb.net, string, tryparse

I'm trying to create a function that checks if a string is in a format of a coordinate (Ex: 362,352), but I can't seem to figure it out correctly. Here is what I have tried:

```
Private Function CheckPointIsValid(ByVal CoordsText As String) As Boolean
    If CoordsText.Contains(",") AndAlso Integer.TryParse(CoordsText = CoordsText.Replace(",", String.Empty), Nothing) Then Return True
    Return False
End Function
```

No matter what is passed to the function always returns false.

Answer (score 1):

Check your TryParse... you had it set to nothing and you forgot an else to return false... see my answer below.

```
 Dim intNumber As Integer = 0
 Dim result As Boolean = Int32.TryParse(CoordsText.Replace(",",String.Empty), intNumber)
```

So here's your function...

```
 Private Function CheckPointIsValid(ByVal CoordsText As String) As Boolean

 Dim intNumber As Integer = 0
 Dim result As Boolean = Int32.TryParse(CoordsText.Replace(",",String.Empty), intNumber)    

  Return CBool(CoordsText.Contains(",") AndAlso result)

 End Function
```

Comment: you  forgot a end if :)

Comment: There actually don't need it

Comment: If i add it in my code without the end if it say's 'If' must end with a matching 'End If'. "aa ok now i see you changed it"

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm now using (It works fine):

```
Private Function CheckPointIsValid(ByVal CoordsText As String) As Boolean
    If CoordsText.Contains(",") AndAlso Integer.TryParse(CoordsText.Replace(",", String.Empty), Nothing) = True Then Return True
    Return False
End Function
```